# Unique coordinates using GenomicRanges

Tags: r, bioconductor

How can  i find unique (non overlapping genomic coordinates) by comparing two datasets using GenomicRanges?

dataset1 =

```
chr start         end       CNA
1   170900001   171500001   loss
1   11840001    19420001    loss
1   60300001    62700001    gain
1   25520001    25820001    gain
```

dataset2 =

```
chr  start       end        CNA
1   170940001   171500001   gain
1   60300001    62700001    gain
1   25520001    25840001    gain
1   119860001   123040001   loss
1   171500001   171580001   gain
1   79240001    84420001    gain
```

expected output

```
     chr     start       end        CNA
     1     170940001 171500001  gain
     1    119860001  123040001    loss
     1    171500001  171580001    gain
     1    79240001   84420001     gain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
require("GenomicRanges"        )

#data
x1 <- read.table(text="chr start         end       CNA
1   170900001   171500001   loss
1   11840001    19420001    loss
1   60300001    62700001    gain
1   25520001    25820001    gain",header=TRUE)

x2 <- read.table(text="chr  start       end        CNA
1   170940001   171500001   loss
1   60300001    62700001    gain
1   25520001    25840001    gain
1   119860001   123040001   loss
1   171500001   171580001   gain
1   79240001    84420001    gain",header=TRUE)

g1 <-  GRanges(seqnames=paste0("chr",x1$chr),
               IRanges(start=x1$start,
                       end=x1$end)
               )

g2 <-  GRanges(seqnames=paste0("chr",x2$chr),
               IRanges(start=x2$start,
                       end=x2$end)
               )

#result
setdiff(g1,g2)

#output
# GRanges object with 2 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
#       seqnames                 ranges strand
#          <Rle>              <IRanges>  <Rle>
#   [1]     chr1 [ 11840001,  19420001]      *
#   [2]     chr1 [170900001, 170940000]      *
#   -------
#   seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

**EDIT:**
Subset based on CNA and setdiff, then merge - `c()`. Although, doesn't match with expected output...

```
#result
g1_loss <- setdiff(g1[g1@elementMetadata$CNA=="loss"],
                   g2[g2@elementMetadata$CNA=="loss"])
g1_loss@elementMetadata$CNA <- "loss"

g2_loss <- setdiff(g2[g2@elementMetadata$CNA=="loss"],
                   g1[g1@elementMetadata$CNA=="loss"])
g2_loss@elementMetadata$CNA <- "loss"

g1_gain <- setdiff(g1[g1@elementMetadata$CNA=="gain"],
                   g2[g2@elementMetadata$CNA=="gain"])
g1_gain@elementMetadata$CNA <- "gain"

g2_gain <- setdiff(g2[g2@elementMetadata$CNA=="gain"],
                   g1[g1@elementMetadata$CNA=="gain"])
g2_gain@elementMetadata$CNA <- "gain"

#merge
c(g1_gain,g2_gain,g1_loss,g1_gain)

#output
# GRanges object with 5 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#     seqnames                 ranges strand |         CNA
#        <Rle>              <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>
# [1]     chr1 [ 25820002,  25840001]      * |        gain
# [2]     chr1 [ 79240001,  84420001]      * |        gain
# [3]     chr1 [170940001, 171580001]      * |        gain
# [4]     chr1 [ 11840001,  19420001]      * |        loss
# [5]     chr1 [170900001, 171500001]      * |        loss
# -------
#   seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

Comment: @zx8754..finding unique overlaps does work in the previous case. But what in case if i also want to consider CNAs for finding the unique for coordinates. I have updated the example

Comment: yes. i want  to compare the coordinates (start and end) and also the CNA for finding out the unique regions. In the example the CNA of the first overlapping segment doesn't match.

Comment: @zx i took only g1_loss and g1_gain to get my output. it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75308/discussion-between-beginner-and-zx8754).